# jquery "slide down and unhide div" not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, toggle, hide, slide

here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#hidearea').toggle();    

    $('#scroll').click(function(){
        $('#hidearea').toggle(800);                      
    }); 

    $('#container').localScroll();  

});
```

and the html:

```
<div id="container"> <a id="scroll" href="#scrollto">Scroll to ...</a></div> 

     <div style="height:500px; width:200px; border:thick solid blue"></div>

     <a id="scrollto">Box #4</a>

  <div id="hidearea"> 
    <div style="height:1000px; width:200px; border:thin solid black;"></div>
  </div>
```

The page is not scrolling down to "Box #4"
This works correctly in all browsers including IE10 - 11 **except** IE9 
could anyone please help

Comment: What is _localScroll_?

Comment: localsrcroll() http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html